# MongoDB & Node.js - How to sum a field with $eq and $cond where the expression is an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

we have this code. Please check that we have these properties in the

```
$project:
sumVentaWp
sumVentaMail
sumAlquilerWp
sumAlquilerMail
```

The main goal is to get a sum with a condition, the problem is that `dwellingDetail` and `dwellingDetail.publicationType` are arrays of objects and I think we can't compare it to "Venta" (that's why it's always returning 0). 
`$eq: ["$dwellingDetail.publicationType", "Venta"]`
Is there a way to check a particular object in dwellingDetail?

````
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            localField: '_id',
                            from: 'inquiries', //the collection name, (bad)before i had Phrase as the model
                            foreignField: 'agencyId',
                            as: 'inquiries'
                        },

                    },

                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            localField: 'inquiries.dwellingId',
                            from: 'dwelling', //the collection name, (bad)before i had Phrase as the model
                            foreignField: '_id',
                            as: 'dwellingDetail'
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        $match: {
                            'deleted': false,

                        }
                    },                    

                    { $sort: { name: 1 } },


                    {
                        $project: {
                            agencyname: '$name',
                            agencyId: '$_id',
                            sumVentaWp: {
                                $sum: { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$dwellingDetail.publicationType", "Venta"] }, then: 1, else: 0 } }
                            },
                            sumVentaMail: {
                                $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$dwellingDetail.publicationType', "Venta"] }, 1, 0] }
                            },
                            sumAlquilerWp: {
                                $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$dwellingDetail.publicationType', "Alquiler"] }, 1, 0] }
                            },
                            sumAlquilerMail: {
                                $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$dwellingDetail.publicationType', "Alquiler"] }, 1, 0] }
                            },
                            pubType: '$dwellingDetail.publicationType',

                            whatsappcounter: {
                                $sum: '$inquiries.whatsappcounter'
                            },
                            mailcounter: { $sum: '$inquiries.mailcounter' },
                            'detail._id': '0'
                        }
                    }

                ]).exec();```
````

Comment: just checking why do you've same condition `{ $eq: ['$dwellingDetail.publicationType', "Alquiler"] }` for two fields `sumAlquilerWp` & `sumAlquilerMail` ?

Comment: Is it working or still having issues ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare `['Venta']` with `'Venta'` instead you can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) :

```
{
    $project: {
        agencyname: '$name',
        agencyId: '$_id',
        sumVentaWp: {
            $sum: { $cond: [{ $in: [ "Venta","$dwellingDetail.publicationType"] }, then: 1, else: 0 ] }
        },
        sumVentaMail: {
            $sum: { $cond: [{ $in: [ "Venta", '$dwellingDetail.publicationType'] }, 1, 0] }
        },
        sumAlquilerWp: {
            $sum: { $cond: [{ $in: ["Alquiler",'$dwellingDetail.publicationType'] }, 1, 0] }
        },
        sumAlquilerMail: {
            $sum: { $cond: [{ $in: [ "Alquiler",'$dwellingDetail.publicationType'] }, 1, 0] }
        },
        pubType: '$dwellingDetail.publicationType',

        whatsappcounter: {
            $sum: '$inquiries.whatsappcounter'
        },
        mailcounter: { $sum: '$inquiries.mailcounter' },
        'detail._id': '0'
    }
}
```

**Note :** Just in case if you've multiple conditions to check, You can try using [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html).